How to design split keyboard with USB-C serial interconnect
I'm designing a split keyboard using atmega32u4 (without Pro Micro). Planning to connect the halves via USB-C to USB-C for serial Wiring.
QMK docs state serial connection needs GND, VCC, and D2. Would connecting USB-C's D+ and D- lines together to D2 work for serial communication?

https://docs.qmk.fm/features/split_keyboard#serial-wiring

Hello, which halves do you need with the USB-Cs

It would work, but you don't want to use a standard connector for non-standard purposes.
One small mistake of plugging something into the wrong port or cable hanging from it, and you risk burning up an expensive phone, laptop, tablet, etc.
USB-C receptacles are not allowed to be energized with 5V unless a device requesting power is detected. So it will violate USB specs and other devices may not expect it.
Plugging in a USB-C plug (that is allowed to be energized) means you are able to short two power supplies together accidentally.
So generally, it's an extremely bad idea to repurpose standard connectors for custom purposes. Which is why every time it's been done has caused trouble.
Use another connector, especially if you publish the design, and let other hobbyists copy your design. That's how poor ideas usually start spreading and it's not good for anyone.
